# Is there a way to capture style data using selenium webdriver (python)?

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently looking to pull the specific typography a company uses on stylify me (e.g. for http://stylifyme.com/?stylify=uber.com i want to pull "UberMove, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif, normal, 52px, 56px, #000000"). However, I'm running into issues when it comes to finally pulling the text - the text shows in the html but does not appear when i try to pull the text. I've tried pulling both the Inner HTML and just the text - see example code and text below.

```
page=webdriver.Chrome('/Downloads/chromedriver.exe')
page.get('http://stylifyme.com/')
website_finder=page.find_element_by_id('input-stylify')
website_finder.send_keys('www.bcg.com')
website_finder.submit()

#try 1:
print(page.find_element_by_id("result-header-1-dt").text)
#output 1: "Header 1: Font, Style, Size, Leading, Colour"

#try 2
print(page.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/th/strong').get_attribute("innerHTML"))
#output 2: "Header 1:"
```

HTML code:

```
<th id="result-header-1-dt" class="first" scope="row"><strong style="opacity: 1;">
UberMove, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif, normal, 52px, 56px, #000000
</strong> <span style="opacity: 1;">Font, Style, Size, Leading, Colour</span></th>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263824/get-html-source-of-webelement-in-selenium-webdriver-using-python. Looks very similar to yours.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I took a look at that code and I'm currently using the same method so I'm not sure why it isn't working

Comment: Possibly duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39069497/how-to-extract-the-strong-elements-which-are-in-div-tag

Comment: You just need to wait for it, time.sleep(5)

Comment: Wow, that's totally it....the time sleep worked perfectly! Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

As pguardiario mentioned, the solution is to wait for the element to be loaded. Using `time.sleep(5)` works fine much of the time, but often using a `WebDriverWait` can work better. `time.sleep` sleeps for a set amount of time, which can lead to unnecessary pauses in running the script, or failures if a page takes a really long time to load. `WebDriverWait` helps keep scripts running by finishing once the element is found. If the element is never found, then an Exception will be thrown.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = ...
max_wait_time = 5
selector = ...
by = By.XPATH  # Or By.ID, By.CSS_SELECTOR, etc.

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, max_wait_time).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((by, selector)))
except TimeoutException:
    print("Failed to find an element with", selector, "in", max_wait_time, "seconds)
```